# Doctrine QueryBuilder - nested select statement in aggregate function

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, query-builder

I have a SQL query that uses nested SELECT in an aggregate function (SUM) and it executes with no errors, but I cant seem to get it to work using Doctrine QueryBuilder.

The query basically simplifies to this:

```
SELECT table_1.group, SUM((SELECT amount FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id))
FROM table_1
GROUP BY table_1.group
```

When execution with Doctrine's queryBuilder I get this error:

> exceptionMessage: '[Syntax Error] line 0, col 242: Error: Expected known function, got ''SELECT''' in 'vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:54'

One solution is to not use queryBuilder, but the actual code is way more complex and this means I will have to do a lot of restructuring in my code.

Has anyone came up with something that can trick the Doctrine queryBuilder parser to be able to parse this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can not select the columns that there are not in group by clause

Comment: I've edited the example, It was a typo, because I made it up just for the question.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT t1.[group], SUM(amount)
FROM table_1 as t1 
left join table_2 as t2 on t1.table_1_id = t2.table_1_id
GROUP BY t1.[group]
```